# Having an error with grabbing process IDs in batch

Tags: batch-file, process

**Problem 1:** My code abruptly stops with no output in console.

**Problem 2:** Line 5 of my code doesn't capture the process ID when in the code block, but it does as a standalone command. Could this be because of the set command not working in else blocks?

Here's the goal of the code:

- Check if explorer.exe is running.
- If more than one instance is running, set a variable to multiple.
- Else, if no instances are running, set a variables to not found.
- Else, if one instance is running, dump the memory of explorer.exe.

I expect to grab the process ID of explorer.exe, but the PID is not defined and the program stops at,  I believe, line 2. I've inserted pauses after every line of code, and that's where it happens.

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /I /C "explorer.exe"') do set amount=%%a
if %amount% GTR 1 (
    set multiple-explorer=  - [ALERT] Multiple instances of explorer.exe found.
) else (
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" /fo table /nh') do set PID=%%j
    if "%PID%" EQU "No" (
        set explorer=  - [ALERT] explorer.exe not found.
    ) else (
        echo  [#] Dumping memory of explorer.exe...
        strings2.exe -pid %PID% -nh > explorer.txt
    )
)
```

My goal for this code is also to make it as compact as possible without any goto lines.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are setting *and* using `PID` inside an `else` (code block) what requires [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Just be aware that `if "%PID%" EQU "No"` will very likely be language dependent!